# PHP <title> array in head only works partially

Tags: php, arrays, content-management-system, title, head

For a simple CMS website with a few pages I am experimenting with an array in the head section which overwrites/replaces the titles of individual pages. This is what I have until now:

```
<?php 
$pageTitles = array(
    'page01' => 'Nice title 01',
    'page02' => 'Nice title 02',
);

$pageTitle = isset($pageTitles[$page]) ? $page : 'Home';
```

HTML

```
<title>Overall website title - <?= ucfirst($pageTitle); ?></title>
```

As far as I can see, the code is correct. Still, only page01, page02 is displayed in the title (the page document name), so it is at least partially working. Temporarily fixed things with `echo ucfirst`, but I'm looking to have the entire titles of the array displayed. These are ignored for some reason.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I cannot see `$page` anywhere.

Comment: Jake125, please upvote my answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shuold use and index for referring to right value (the page o something other)

```
<title>Overall website title - <?= ucfirst($pageTitle[$yourIndex]); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course only `$page` is displayed!

You're telling your app that you want `$pageTitle` to be `$page`, if the given key is set. So you're echo-ing the key in the title tag.

What you **meant** to do was:

```
$pageTitle = isset($pageTitles[$page]) ? $pageTitles[$page] : 'Home';
```